# PHP and MySQLi - Upload Multiple Image

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am planning to make an image galary using PHP with MySQL as a database.

I already make a multiple upload images using PHP but I got a problem. When I uploaded **8 images** in database only show 1 row data. But in folder there are **8 images** that I have upload.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="a.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload">    
</form>

<?php
include_once 'koneksi.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
        $filepath = "uploads/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO files (file,path,type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {        
header("Location: a.php");    
} else {        
header("Location: a.php");    
}     
    }

    $connect->close();}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks for ur feedback :)

Comment: Show us your database structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE files`

Comment: and what does `var_dump($_FILES)` give you? Is that output what you expect?

Comment: And do you have any PHP errors?

Comment: id(int 11) PK AI, file (varchar 250), path (varchar 100), type (varchar 100).

No error in my php code

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and put the details in the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move the `header location` redirect outside the `for` loop.
Also Refer [Upload multiple images and store their path in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333269/upload-multiple-images-and-store-their-path-in-database).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="a.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload">    
</form>

<?php
include_once 'koneksi.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
        $filepath = "uploads/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO files (`file`,`path`,`type`) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
    $connect->query($sql);

    }
if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {        
header("Location: a.php");    
exit; // always add exit after header Location:
} else {        
header("Location: a.php");  
exit;  // always add exit after header Location:
}  
    $connect->close();}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do u mean ?

Comment: See the Edited Answer

Comment: it's still store 1 row data in DB

Answer (score 0):

After some code beautification of your snippet answer became obvious - you only get one new row in database, because in your `for` loop you redirect user to `a.php` right after inserting this row.
In other words your `for` loop will always perform one and only one step.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="a.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <?php
    include_once 'koneksi.php';

    if (isset($_POST['btn_upload'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++) {
            $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
            $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
            $filepath = "uploads/".$filename;

            move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO files (file, path, type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
            // #NOTICE: Read about SQL Injection and why above SQL is bad.

            // #SOLUTION: Place 1

            if ($connect->query($sql) === true) {
                header("Location: a.php");
                exit;  // #NOTICE: Always add `exit` after "header Location:"
            } else {
                header("Location: a.php");
                exit;  // #NOTICE: Always add `exit` after "header Location:"
            }
        }

        $connect->close();

        // #SOLUTION: Place 2
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you see it now?

Checkout link below! File [[1]](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44346949/a.php) is your file after performing some cleaning. It's also contains two comments marked as `#SOLUTION`. `Place 1` is the code you should move to `Place 2`. After moving you should also change `if` condition to check if all files were uploaded correctly.  File [[2]](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44346949/b.php) on the other hand is edited by me with (probably) proper solution for your problem.

I hope I helped!

https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44346949/

EDIT: @AdhershMNair:
I think that because of line `if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {` in your solution, data for last uploaded file will be inserted into database twice (once for last iteration in `for` loop and once for `if` statement).